# Change format in Android Chronometr to show millisecond

Tags: java, android

i'd like to change format in my android chronometr to show millisecond. So far I used this tip:

```
    mChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
            long t = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
            cArg.setText(DateFormat.format("kk:mm:ss", t));
        }
    });
```

but i dont know the symbols for millisecond. Is there something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
   mChronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
            long t = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
            cArg.setText(DateFormat.format("kk:mm:ss:SSS", t));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already tried this and it actualy doesn't work. It looks like this: http://d.pr/i/8Qce ... or do I have to change something more?

Anyway thanks.